# Composer: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: laravel, apache, ssl, wamp, wampserver

`[Composer\Downloader\TransportException] SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate`

I have this problem when trying to run **Composer install**

Im using WAMP 3.2.0
Laravel 7.7 ( Just upgraded, but this issue was prevalent before upgrade already )

Both **php.ini** and **phpForApache.ini**

*extension=openssl*  `ACTIVE`

*curl.cainfo = "E:\wamp\bin\php\php7.4.0\cacert.pem"*  `ACTIVE`
*openssl.cafile="E:\wamp\bin\php\php7.4.0\cacert.pem"*  `ACTIVE`

**httpd.conf**
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so  `ACTIVE`

Im not sure what im missing and it does not seem that anything is logged anywhere.

**I have tried multiple Stackoverflow solutions, but non worked sofar**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removed this environment variable and it works now.

[image]